# How to add css-loader and stylus-loader into nuxt.config.js?

Tags: javascript, css-loader, nuxt.js, stylus-loader

I create an [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation) skeleton:

```
yarn create nuxt-app myapp
```

Then I add css-loader and stylus loader:

```
yarn add css-loader
yarn add stylus stylus loader
```

I then add them to nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ['css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

I get this when I run `yarn run dev`:

```
begueradj@begueradj:~/myapp$ yarn run dev
yarn run v1.10.1
$ nuxt


 INFO  Building project

✔ success Builder initialized
✔ success Nuxt files generated


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                                         16:03:01

 error  in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-403 14:3-18:5 15:22-411
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-405 14:3-18:5 15:22-413
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-379 14:3-18:5 15:22-387
 @ ./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./components/Logo.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-386 14:3-18:5 15:22-394
 @ ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js



 READY  Listening on http://localhost:3000



 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                                         16:03:02

 error  in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-403 14:3-18:5 15:22-411
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-405 14:3-18:5 15:22-413
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-379 14:3-18:5 15:22-387
 @ ./components/Logo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./components/Logo.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js

 error  in ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 | 



 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-386 14:3-18:5 15:22-394
 @ ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./components/VuetifyLogo.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Why I added these loaders into nuxt.config.js? Because, for instance, on [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) it says installing the loader is not enough unless you extend the webpack configuration. And to do so in Nuxt, we have to do it [similarly](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack) to what I did (I suppose)

Comment: You dont need to add loader in config. It is already configured. You just need to install loaders

Comment: Could you provide a link that supports your statement?

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/ although it miss the stylus, need to update docs

Comment: I saw that link before, I was not confident in my understanding though ... I think you are right, I will one basic test and come back, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your discussion helps me!
My steps(if you have stylus globally):

```
npm install stylus-loader stylus --save-dev
```

And that's it. After that you can automatically use stylus in your project.

Answer (score 1):

> [Quite a long delayed answer. But will help someone for recent nuxt versions (^2.14)]

A solution from issue discussion [nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/148)
with ref to  [webpack stylus options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/stylus-loader/#stylusoptions)
and for nuxt latest (2.14.7),

extend webpack configuration mapping all loaders,

```
build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      [].concat(...config.module.rules.find(e => e.test.toString().match(/\.styl/)).oneOf.map(e => e.use.filter(e => e.loader == 'stylus-loader'))).forEach(stylus => { 
        Object.assign(stylus.options, {
          //preferPathResolver: 'webpack',
          sourceMap: true,
          stylusOptions: { 
            //use: ['nib'],
            include: ['~assets/styles'],  //include all styl files from folder
            import: [
              '~assets/style/main.styl',  //your main styl file
            ],
          },
        })
        //console.log(stylus)
      }) 
    },
```

this imports the files and include stylus folder as well.